# Ratios with Ages

Tags: ratio

The ratio of Sam's age to his son John's age is 8:3. If the sum of their ages is 55 years, what is the age difference between John and his dad in years?

So, I divided 55 by 11 and got 5, then multiplied that by 8 to get Sam's age (40), then the obvious remaining 15 years belong to John.

According to the answer key, the answer is 25. Can someone please explain how it is 25?

Comment: Who's Adam?????

Comment: Sorry, it was an error.

Comment: @John And $40-15$ is...

Comment: you have got age of sam and john i.e $40$ and $15$.In question age difference is asked so difference is $40-15=25$. clear?

Comment: @Przemysław Scherwentke: On your [homepage](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/72361/przemys%C5%82aw-scherwentke) I think you want to say that [English is not your mother tongue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_language)

Comment: @miracle173 Thank you! Correcting.

Comment: 40 - 15 = 25... Sorry, I usually make simple mistakes like these.

Answer (score 1):

${s \over j} = { 8 \over 3}$ gives $3 s -8 j = 0$, and $s+j = 55$.

Solving gives $s=40, j=15$. The difference is 25.

Comment: You're solving using substitution, right?

Comment: Yes. It is the simplest here.

Answer (score 0):

Given, $8:3$ multiply both sides by $x$, $8x:3x$, Now sum of their ages is $55$.

$8x+3x=55$

$11x=55$

$x=5$,

John's age, $=3\cdot x= 5\cdot3=15, $ and that of his father,$=8\cdot 5$=40

Difference, $=40-15=25$